# Handle ODBC resources (pointers) in modern C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement MS SQL ODBC connection in C++.

I'd like to make a thin RAII wrapper over the C flow as it relies on macro/return code/goto exit statements in order to release the acquired resources. Bellow is the example code, I have found in the documentation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sql.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <string.h>

#define RESULT_LEN  256

#define CHECK_ERROR(e, s, h, t) ({\
        if (e!=SQL_SUCCESS && e != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {extract_error(s, h, t); goto exit;} \
})

void extract_error(char *fn, SQLHANDLE handle, SQLSMALLINT type)
{
    SQLINTEGER i = 0;
    SQLINTEGER NativeError;
    SQLCHAR SQLState[7];
    SQLCHAR MessageText[256];
    SQLSMALLINT TextLength;
    SQLRETURN ret;

    fprintf(stderr, "\nThe driver reported the following error %s\n", fn);
    do
    {
        ret = SQLGetDiagRec(type, handle, ++i, SQLState, &NativeError,
             MessageText, sizeof(MessageText), &TextLength);
        if (SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
            printf("%s:%ld:%ld:%s\n",
            SQLState, (long)i, (long)NativeError, MessageText);
        }
    } while (ret == SQL_SUCCESS);
}

int main()
{
    SQLHENV   henv = SQL_NULL_HENV;   // Environment
    SQLRETURN retcode;

    // Allocate environment handle
    retcode = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &henv);
    CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV)", henv, SQL_HANDLE_ENV);

    exit:
        printf("\nComplete.\n");
        // Free handles
        // Environment
        if (henv != SQL_NULL_HENV)
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, henv);
    return 0;
}
```

The `SQLHENV` is just a `typedef` over `void*` and is initialized from the `SQL_NULL_HENV`, which expands to `0`. Later in the `SQLAllocHandle`, it is changed to the address of the allocated structure from the driver manager.

According to the documentation, the cleanup logic after the `exit` label could fail and the acquired pointer will not be freed.

If I put this logic in the destructor (following the RAII guidelines), it seems like there will be a leak in the cases the driver manager fails to deallocate the resource.

I believe, throwing in destructor is bad practice, so I don't really want to go this way.

Is there a good way to handle this issue or I should accept the memory leak possibility?

Any help is welcomed. Thank you.

Comment: For APIs whose initialization functions expect double pointers as input -rather than return pointer- there's no thin RAII layer. You need a conversion function that changes the former to later form. For the later case, simple solutions involve carful use of `std::unique_ptr` with custome deleter.

Comment: Example: https://gist.github.com/meshell/876f1e01c7e72994b126

Comment: This is good too: https://sheep.horse/2021/3/use_std--unique_ptr_to_safely_wrap_handles.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is reasonable to expect that:

1. If the resource was properly allocated
2. It has not already been deallocated, and
3. It can only be deallocated once any usage of that resource has ended and it is otherwise unused and no longer referenced in any way

Then the attempt to deallocate the resource is expected to succeed.

If it fails, it is a catastrophic situation for which no clean solution can be reasonably expected to exist.

In such cases, `abort()` gets typically called, to pull the plug on the sorry situation.

Note the trick is to make sure the third condition is properly enforced. So, for example and loosely speaking: if this SQL handle is currently being used to execute a statement, or used in some other way, then the class cannot be destroyed. This also needs to be enforced, in one way or another.